# laravel get unique results filter by a column value

Tags: laravel

I have a user table in which there is column `Membership Id`. I need to fetch rows which do not have duplicate value for `Membership Id` column. For Example, this is my table structure

```
ID   Name  Membership Id 
1    xxx   123
2    xxx   124
3    xxx   124 
4    xxx   125
```

In output, I want to skip rows which have duplicate values for Membership Id and want to fetch only last row so output should be row 1,3,4 from above example

Comment: I don't know how laravel works but in SQL that could be done with a "Distinct" Keyword.

Comment: laravel also have Distinct keyword but i don't know how to use for only one  column

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery JOIN:

```php
$join = User::select('membership_id', DB::raw('max(id) id'))
    ->groupBy('membership_id');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') as latest';
$users = User::join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
    $join->on('users.membership_id', 'latest.membership_id')
        ->on('users.id', 'latest.id');
})->get();
```

In Laravel 5.6.17 you can use [`joinSub()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins):

```php
$join = User::select('membership_id', DB::raw('max(id) id'))
    ->groupBy('membership_id');
$users = User::joinSub($join, 'latest', function($join) {
    $join->on('users.membership_id', 'latest.membership_id')
        ->on('users.id', 'latest.id');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Eloquent

```
MyModel::distinct()->get(['column_name']);
```

for you

```
User::distinct()->get(['Membership Id']);
```

Comment: I think you didn't posted the entire response

Answer (score 0):

Via eloquent

```
User::select('Membership_Id')->distinct()->get();
```

Vie db facade

```
DB::table('users')->select('Membership_Id')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: but this query will return  Membership_Id and i want all table values